# Azure.Storage.Queues: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value'). - Error during Azure function run

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm trying to run an Azure function as a docker image but I'm getting this strange log:

```
Azure.Storage.Queues: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value').
An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down.
```

I'm not understanding what this "value" means.
I'm sure to have configured correctly all the configuration values.
Here's the local.settings.json :

```
{"IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "14.16.0",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://azurite:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://azurite:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://azurite:10002/devstoreaccount1;",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files",
    "MY_CONNECTION_STRING": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://azurite:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://azurite:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://azurite:10002/devstoreaccount1;"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {}
}
```

And this is the host.json file :

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "DurableTask.AzureStorage": "Warning",
      "DurableTask.Core": "Warning",
    },
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "hubName": "HubName",
      "localRpcEndpointEnabled": false,
      "storageProvider": {
        "connectionStringName": "MY_CONNECTION_STRING"
      },
      "tracing": {
        "traceInputsAndOutputs": false,
        "traceReplayEvents": false
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Could you help me please ?

Comment: are you only running locally? if not, is the config value for the online function set for the storage correctly? the trigger is a queue item? do you maybe try to access a null value from a parsed message in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure.Storage.Queues: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value').
> An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down.

As per your configuration, the issue seems to be related to the connection string for the storage account.

**To resolve this:**

1. Check if "MY_CONNECTION_STRING" value of your storage account in `local.settings.json` is correct and be sure that the storage account you are pointing to, *is not deleted.*

***you can follow two workarounds:***

**Workaround 1:**
Change local.setting.json as below:

- Add "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" as value of "AzureWebJobsStorage".

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "14.16.0",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files",
    "MY_CONNECTION_STRING": "your_storageaccount-Connectionstring
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {}
}
```

Try changing the connection string format:

`"MyconnectionString":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=kvpstorageaccount;AccountKey=1Lj/Uq5cMD7eNMIh9R0bReXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net`

***you can copy it from your storage Account=>Access keys:***

[image]

*- you can use same `host.json` configuration.*

**Workaround 2:**

***local.settings.json:***

```
{"IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "14.16.0",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage":"your_connection_string",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files",    
  "ConnectionStrings": {}
}
```

- In the host.json file, update the "storageProvider" section of the "durableTask" as shown below:
  `"connectionStringName":"MY_CONNECTION_STRING"` to `"connectionStringName":"AzureWebJobsStorage"`.

***host.json:***

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "DurableTask.AzureStorage": "Warning",
      "DurableTask.Core": "Warning",
    },
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "hubName": "HubName",
      "localRpcEndpointEnabled": false,
      "storageProvider": {
        "connectionStringName": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
      },
      "tracing": {
        "traceInputsAndOutputs": false,
        "traceReplayEvents": false
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

This aligns properly with the connection string defined in local.settings.json.

- Debug and check locally before pushing the changes.
- Push the changes to docker image, Rebuild and Redeploy the image.